# How to include mysql-Server in Java Program

Tags: java, mysql, installation

Is it possible to have a mysql server included in my java application?

Now I need the user of my program installing MySQL on his own and executing several commands before installing my application. That's not acceptable...

Comment: As far as I know there were attempts to create embedded installation of mysql (maven artifact mysql-connector-mxj-gpl). But support for them was discontinued by MySQL quite long ago. I'd advise you to either migrate to embedded database (like hsqldb, h2) or to think about using docker container to simplify installation (if it's possible).

Comment: If I knew that, I'd used hsqldb directly... Thanks!

Comment: @NikitaSapozhnikov Does HSQLDB support exactly the same SQL Syntax?

Comment: Both hsqldb and h2 support mysql compatibility layer. Unfortunately you still may need to change some queries. For example functions without arguments shouldn't have braces in queries (so `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` should be replaced with just `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`). You can enable compatibility mode in hsqldb by adding ` sql.syntax_mys=true` to end of jdbc url (after semicolon).

Comment: Thanks, I've done a little testing with an embedded server, it seems integrating hsqldb won't be that difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. Use an embedded server like HSQLDB, which also accepts the same SQL Syntax as MySQL (tested it).